# "Page Not Found" upon deploying site to Netlify via Github repo

Tags: html, css, github, netlify

I'm a complete beginner to web development and am trying to deploy my first site via Netlify. Despite my site working fine when being displayed from my local machine, I'm given the following error when navigating to my site's URL:

> **Page Not Found**
> Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
> Back to our site

Since my page is functional on my local machine, I believe the error lies within my Github repo and/or my deploy settings. Here's my repo:

https://github.com/Cotton0419/TestSite

And my deploy settings:

> Repository: github.com/Cotton0419/TestSite 
> Base directory: acme 
> Build command: Not set 
> Publish directory: acme/disp 
> Deploy log visibility: Logs are public

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can supplement more information if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Base directory` on Netlify is only used by the build environment for a reference to your code base (defaults to root of the repository if not given).

The `Publish directory` would be relative to the base directory. So in your case `disp` or `acme/disp` if using the default.

You are referencing assets in a location that does not exist in your published paths, so they would not exist in your deploy to the CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

You should move your assets into your deploy `disp` folder and edit the correct paths into your code files.

[image]

Comment: So this worked perfectly, but only when the .css .html and .jpgs are directly in the disp folder. It didn't work when they were in their respective folders (all in the disp folder) like I had them originally. Is there a way around that, or is that just how it has to be? Thanks so much!

Comment: Think of the `disp` folder as the root of your website. You can put the assets at any level under that location as long as the references to those assets is correctly changed also. So put the css in `disp/css/style.css` and make sure the reference is relative to the `/css/style.css` location.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem I encountered today. I decided to upload an old portfolio I had made a while back. Then for some reason after running the URL on Netlify, nothing happened. The only thing that showed up was a prompt similar to yours -

> **Page Not Found**
>
> Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
>
> Back to our site

After revisiting the HTML and CSS files, I realized that I had set the title for my HTML file to **porfolio.html** instead of **index.html** which solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

For this kind of error please kindly check the HTML filename change it into index.html it worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33657492)